# C# - Play a video from a server with embedded vlc player?

Tags: c#, video, server, stream

In my Winforms application I have a DataGridView with the data of my database. In the data the file path of the video is also deposited. The path should be handed over to the VLC player and then play the video.

With the local file path it is working. But the video is not played, as soon as the videos are on the server.

How can I play the videos from the server without having them locally on the PC?

Code where the datagridview is:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        Wiedergabe wiedergabe = new Wiedergabe(path); // new form with the player

        wiedergabe.Show();
    }
```

Then in the form which should play the video:

```
    public Wiedergabe(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.path = path;
    }

    private void Wiedergabe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vlc_Player.volume = 50;
        vlc_Player.playlist.add("file:///"+path);
    }
```

Comment: How do you access the server? Which protocol are you using?

Comment: I think its TCP/IP and Shared Memory

Comment: Let me ask this way: How does a server path look like? E.g. `\\server\path\file`

Comment: It looks like this: \\server\\d$\\Test_Media\\Videos\\Pigeon.mp4

Comment: OK, now you need to add the code you're using. See [mcve].

Comment: Added a bit code. This was just the code, where I get the path of the video and play it in the other form

Comment: The code "fails", if you don't provide credentials when accessing the share and none are available in the local credentials manager.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to have access to your server by either already having entered the credentials (credentials are already in the `Credentials Store`) or by manually adding them.

First of all we have to check whether the Network share is accessible by using

```
//Wiedergabe.cs / Form_Load
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
```

In your example, you stated that your file is located at `\\server\\d$\\Test_Media\\Videos\\Pigeon.mp4`. So `dir` would be `\\server\\d$\\Test_Media\\Videos`.

To store the credentials in the store, we need to have the server name (`server`). Let's use a simple Regular Expression for that:

```
private readonly string regexPatternShare = @"\\\\(.*?)\\";

string share = Regex.Match(dir, regexPatternShare).Groups[1].Value; //returns server
```

Download the NuGet Package `Windows Credentials Manager Api` by entering this in your NuGet console:

> Install-Package Simple.CredentialManager -Version 1.0.0

Build a form, that has a username and password `TextBox` and save the credentials via:

```
Credential shareCred = new Credential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, share, CredentialType.DomainPassword);
shareCred.PersistenceType = PersistenceType.LocalComputer;
shareCred.Save();
```

Then you should be ready to go, the files should be accessible.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this. But is it possible to use the Windows Authentication as the credentials ? That would be great.

Comment: Normally it should do this automatically. Are your sure, you're using the same credentials? (Active Directory?) You can get your credentials by calling `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. But you can't get a password that way (obviously).